# Laravel: HTTPS in Form::open()

Tags: php, ssl, laravel, cloudflare, laravel-form

I'm using SSL for my website (Cloudflare HTTPS) in my login for weh I use ``, Laravel won't convert my website link to SSL version and it shows `http` version. How can I force Laravel to use `https` for me?

For example:

```
<?=Form::open(array('id' =>'submit'))?>

   . . .

<?=Form::close()?>
```

And the result will be:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="submit">

</form>
```

I want `action` to be a `HTTPS` link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use `https` you need to manually give path which will be set to action.

You need to use `URL::to` this way:

```
<?=Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('/', array(), true), 'id' =>'submit' ))?>
```

to make submit to `/` url (which will be equivalent to `example.com`) and pass as 3rd parameter `true` to make it secure