# Laravel form HTTPS action

Tags: php, laravel, https

I'm using Laravel in an application that I would like to be HTTPS-only.

In one view that is shown on `https://example.com/p` I open a form like this:

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => "POST", "id" => "whatever"]) }}
```

Laravel parses it to this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com/p" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="whatever">
```

This looks good on the first sight, but remember, this is on an HTTPS page so I get a mixed-content warning when displaying the page.

But it gets even worse. I configured my server to redirect HTTP request to the according HTTPS resource. That means, my browser posts the form content to the server, which redirects it to the HTTPS-location. The browser then drops the POST-request and sends a regular GET-request to the server which results in exactly the same page the use has seen before.

Why does Laravel fill in the wrong protocol? How can I set the right one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel: HTTPS in Form::open()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427443/laravel-https-in-formopen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your routes with `https` option and call that route to form action.
For Example"

*Route*

```
Route::group(array('https'), function(){
    // all of our routes
    //for your form acction
    Route::post('form', array('as' => 'form/action', 'uses' => 'ExampleController@postForm'));  
}
```

So the route under https group should be https, even route for form to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now every link just throws a 404 error, with and without HTTPS.

Comment: right, can you provide me example url you are try to..?

Comment: It worked as it made the right link but it didn't detect the routes. Guess there is something broken with my configuration. Your answer was correct though.