# Auto secure form on Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and everything looks fine. But I have a problem with the SSL when I use `Form::open()` Function. It always using HTTP without SSL even when the site is using SSL.

I saw this question: [Laravel: HTTPS in Form::open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427443/laravel-https-in-formopen) But there's 2 problems with that: I need to do it manually for each form. and when I program on my Wamp Server, I have HTTP so it won't work on my localhost.

So my question is, How can I auto secure the form if the site is using SSL?

Comment: How do you generate you URL in the Form::open() function?

Comment: @MrShibby - `{{ Form::open(['action' => 'NewsletterController@store']) }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a route group with the `https` option, and insert all of your routes inside that group.

Example:

```
Route::group(array('https'), function(){
    // All routes goes here
});
```

Then your forms should be `https`.

Another solution may be just:

```
URL::forceSchema("https");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Request::secure()` to check if the request is over HTTPS and use the return value in the URL helper like this:

```
Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('/', array(), Request::secure())))
```

This way you form should automatically use HTTP or HTTPS depending if the current request is using HTTPS or not.

Comment: That's a great solution, but he mentioned that he don't want to edit every form.